# membership in C#\winforms

Tags: c#, database, winforms, membership

Please tell me whether "membership" class in winforms \ wpf? If yes, how to use it? I want to make a login screen for the program, so that when you click on login to check the data on a server and then let in the user or not. Thank you!

Comment: Use the System.DirectoryServices namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please tell me whether "membership" class in winforms \ wpf?

No. It is not that simple, you know.

> I want to make a login screen for the program, so that when you click on login to check the data 
>   on a server and then let in the user or not.

it is callled programming. YOu sit down and write code.

Ok, there is a membership service that you cn use (the same as in ASP.NET) but even then - it still would require programming because no visual elements are provided (so: no "form" only methods on classes). Best bet is to sit down and get going ;)

Comment: to my mind comes isprlzovanie MD5 and most design database. This is the right decision?

Comment: isprlzovanie = not english. Please use a dictionary. And yes and no - it is like "cooking, to my mind comes pepper, is that the right decision". If you have a problem on that level, a book about programming may be better than asking random questions.